# Custom Authentication in django is not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I am new to django and I wanted to authenticate user on `email` or `username` with `password` hence I wrote a custom authentication as shown in documentation but it doesn't seem to be called and I have no idea what do I do?

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backend.AuthBackend',)
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username_or_email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username_or_email, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            return reverse('task:home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Username or password is invalid")
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
    else:
         return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

**backend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q


class AuthBackend(object):
    supports_object_permissions = True
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        print('inside custom auth')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                Q(username=username) | Q(email=username) )
            print(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        print(user)
        if user.check_password(password):
             return user
        else:
            return None
```

I wrote this `print` statements in my class to check if they are being called and being written in console. However, they are not being printed and the `print` statement in `views.py` prints `None`

Comment: Do you know which print statement prints `None`, there are multiple instances and how do you know that its from `views.py`? And please post the error part  also for convenience.

Comment: there is no error in console, it just doesn't work and the print within view prints none

Comment: how do you know `None` is from `views.py`?

Comment: because if i comment it then None won't be printed in console anymore

Comment: No thats not what I meant, I meant there are also `print(user)` lines in `backend.py` and `views.py`. Isn't it possible that `None` is printed from `backend.py`?

Comment: No because when I comment the print in views.py None will no more be printed which means it is the statement responsible for printing nonw

Comment: Not much anyone can do you know without knowing whats the error, which docu did you use?

Comment: That is the real problem, there is no error and still it doesn't work. I referred Official documentation of django.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `extend` the `ModelBackend` from `django.contrib.auth.backends`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

User = get_user_model()

class AuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    supports_object_permissions = True
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        print('inside custom auth')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                Q(username=username) | Q(email=username) )
            print(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        print(user)
        if user.check_password(password):
             return user
        else:
            return None
```

And also in `settings.py` don't forget to add your custom backend authentication

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backend.AuthBackend'
]
```

#### Another Possible Solution

From you code what I am seeing is that you want your `email` should treat as user_name of `User` model. You can easily modify `Django's` `AbstructUser` model like following

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
      # your necessary additional fields 
       USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # add this line
```

Now `email` field will treat as an user_name field. No need to add custom `authentication-backend`

Comment: I extended ModelBackend and then imported my AuthBackend class instead of importing django's auth class and now it is working.

Comment: however I am directly importing my AuthBackend class, is it the correct way?

Comment: Depends on what purpose you are working. If you are developing custom module for big project or you have interest to publish your app in `pypi` then my recommendation to you, you should not. Other people may intend to do authentication that may cause problem. Otherwise this is totally upto you. If you just working in a learning project.

Comment: what kind of problems do you mean to say?

Comment: Instead of login , there are other purpose where people may intend to use `authentication` to verify user like for custom permission.  If you are not properly adding your custom authentication in your settings than that may cause problem. 
In peer development, you may need to add documentation or inform your other team members about it, otherwise ideal behaviour of authentication why not working can be a big surprise to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188292/discussion-between-shakil-and-pritesh-thaker).

Comment: Ohkay, thanks for pointing these things out as I have started django just a week ago.

Comment: Good luck @PriteshThaker. And one more thing if you think this answer is good enough please accept this as an answer. So that other people may know this issue is solved.

Comment: This answer did help but it is not the exact solution I applied as I have imported my custom auth directly that is why I haven't accepted it so that people don't misunderstand, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from accounts.models import Token

User = get_user_model()


class PasswordlessAuthenticationBackend:

    def authenticate(self, uid=None):
        print('uuuuuuuuu')
        print('uid', uid, file=sys.stderr)
        if not Token.objects.filter(uid=uid).exists():
            print('no token found', file=sys.stderr)
            return None
        token = Token.objects.get(uid=uid)
        print('got token', file=sys.stderr)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=token.email)
            print('got user', file=sys.stderr)
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print('new user', file=sys.stderr)
            return User.objects.create(email=token.email)

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```